# SQLite in Android doesn't store 2 rows with same value in a particular non-key column

Tags: android, sqlite

OK. So here is the problem I'm having. I'm trying to design an app that acts as a simple task reminder. I have successfully created a database with 4 columns: Name, Date, Priority and whether the task has been completed or not, the first 3 being text, the last an integer. Name is the primary key.

Name and date are entered via text boxes (I'll add a calendar soon enough). Priority is input via a radio group.
Now I haven't added any checks for Name not being present in the database already, so the app crashes when I input the same name, which is ok for now.

Here is my issue: Whenever I select a radio button in the radio group to set a priority to the same as a task that has already been entered before (irrespective of when it has been entered), the row which has an identical value for the task is now replaced. No errors, nothing.
And if, based on the selected radio button, I change the text stored into the table along with that particular task, the same thing happens. What I mean is this:
Initially, on selecting radio button with priority high, I stored a 2 (as text). Medium was 1, low was 0. So, I could have only 3 rows in the table: each having the latest "task" input by the user which has 2, 1 and 0 respectively in the last column. Thinking it was the numbers that caused the problem, I replaced them with "HIGH", "MEDIUM" , "LOW" respectively. But now, I can have a max of 6 rows: with the value of the last column being 0,1,2,HIGH,MEDIUM,LOW.

To clarify, here's a runtime example:
Name: a
Date: 12/12/2012
PR:   HIGH

In table:
a      12/12/2012      HIGH

Name: b
Date: 12/12/2012
PR: LOW

In table:
a      12/12/2012      HIGH
b      12/12/2012      LOW

Name: c
Date: 10/10/2010
PR: HIGH

In table:
c      10/10/2010      HIGH
b      12/12/2012      LOW

So, the same value in date doesnt cause an issue, only in priority.

Here is the code for the class which handles the SQL part:
`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SQLManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static SQLManager sqlObj = null;
    String currUser = null;

    private SQLManager(Context context) {
        super(context, StoreConst.DBNAME, null, StoreConst.DATABASE_VERSION);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    public static SQLManager createObject(Context context) // Singleton pattern
    {

        if (sqlObj == null)
            sqlObj = new SQLManager(context);

        return sqlObj;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(StoreConst.CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Lite- no upgradation of Tables needed in this project
    }

    public void newTask(String tName, String tDate, String tPr) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Inserting Row
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + StoreConst.TABLENAME + "('"
                + StoreConst.NAME + "', '" + StoreConst.DATE + "', '"
                + StoreConst.PR + "', '" + StoreConst.STATUS + "')  VALUES ('"
                + tName + "', '" + tDate + "', '" + tPr + "', 0);");
        db.close();

    }

    public Cursor getTaskByName(int status) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        /*
         * Cursor cursor = db.query(StoreConst.TABLENAME, null,
         * StoreConst.STATUS + "= " + status, null, StoreConst.NAME, null,
         * " "+StoreConst.NAME+" ASC");
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + StoreConst.TABLENAME,
                null);
        // + " WHERE " + StoreConst.STATUS + "= " + status
        // + " ORDER BY "
        // + StoreConst.NAME + " ASC", null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor getTaskByDate(int status) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(StoreConst.TABLENAME, null, StoreConst.STATUS
                + "= " + status, null, StoreConst.DATE, null, "'"
                + StoreConst.DATE + "' DESC");
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor getTaskByPr(int status) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(StoreConst.TABLENAME, null, StoreConst.STATUS
                + "= " + status, null, StoreConst.PR, null, "'" + StoreConst.PR
                + "' DESC");

        return cursor;
    }

    public void clearDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + StoreConst.TABLENAME);
    }

}
```

Note that the getTaskByName()/Date()/Pr() functions above are used to access the database. As is visible in the commented out section, ive even tried doing the following:
Using quotes before the column name
Adding spaces before the column name
using rawQuery
using execQuery

Here is the StoreConst class:

```
public class StoreConst {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLENAME = "Tasklist";
    final static public String DBNAME = "Userdata.db";
    final static public String NAME = "Task_Name";
    final static public String DATE = "Task_Deadline";
    final static public String PR = "Task_Priority";
    final static public String STATUS = "Task_Status";   // 0 = To Do ; 1 = Done
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLENAME
            + " (" + StoreConst.NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + StoreConst.DATE
            + " TEXT," + StoreConst.PR + " TEXT," + StoreConst.STATUS + " INTEGER"
            + " );";
    public static final String SortBy = "DataBaseSortingOrder";
    public static final String DoStatus = "Do_Status";

}
```

Here is the code I've used to insert the relevant task into the table:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CreateTask extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnCheckedChangeListener {

    Button button_save;
    RadioGroup rg;
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4;
    EditText ed1, ed2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_task);
        getObjects();
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        button_save.setOnClickListener(this);

        // prefs = PreferenceManager
        // .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    }

    private void getObjects() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        button_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddTask);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGPr);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVCreatetsk);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVtskName);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVTskDt);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVtskPriority);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTtskname);
        ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTtskDt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg1) {
        case R.id.rPRhigh:
            Toast.makeText(this, "HIGH PR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.rPRmed:
            Toast.makeText(this, "MED PR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.rPRlow:
            Toast.makeText(this, "LOW PR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SQLManager manager = SQLManager.createObject(getApplicationContext());

        String rId=null;
        switch (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.rPRhigh:
            rId = "High";
            break;
        case R.id.rPRmed:
            rId = "Medium";
            break;
        case R.id.rPRlow:
            rId = "Low";
            break;
        }

        if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1
                && ed1.getText().toString() != ""
                && ed2.getText().toString() != ""
                && ed1.getText().toString() != null
                && ed2.getText().toString() != null) {
            manager.newTask(ed1.getText().toString(), ed2.getText().toString(),
                    rId);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Task Added!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else {
            if (ed1.getText().toString() == null
                    || ed1.getText().toString() == null)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Task Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

        }
        {
            if (ed2.getText().toString() == null
                    || ed2.getText().toString() == null)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Task DeadLine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

        }
        {
            if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Select Task Priority", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

        }
    }

}
```

and its corresponding xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVCreatetsk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CREATE TASKS" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVtskName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Task Name :" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eTtskname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVTskDt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Task DeadLine :" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eTtskDt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVtskPriority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Task Priority :" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rGPr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rPRhigh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:text="High Priority" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rPRmed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:text=" Medium Priority" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rPRlow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:text="Low Priority" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAddTask"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the activity I used to display:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DisplayTaskList extends Activity {

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SQLManager manager;
    TextView t1;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_task_list);

        manager = SQLManager.createObject(getApplicationContext());

        ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        Cursor c=null;
        int status = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(StoreConst.DoStatus);
        String s = getIntent().getExtras().getString(StoreConst.SortBy);

        if (s == StoreConst.NAME) {
            c = manager.getTaskByName(status);
        } else if (s == StoreConst.DATE) {
            c = manager.getTaskByDate(status);
        } else {
            c = manager.getTaskByPr(status);
        }




        populateListView(c, status);

        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
        lview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void populateListView(Cursor c, int status) {

        boolean exist = false;

        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            while (c.getPosition() < c.getCount()) {
                if (c.getInt(3) == status) {
                    temp.put(StoreConst.NAME, c.getString(0));
                    temp.put(StoreConst.DATE, c.getString(1));
                    temp.put(StoreConst.PR, c.getString(2));
                    exist = true;
                }
                list.add(new HashMap<String, String>(temp));
                c.moveToNext();
                temp.clear();
            }
        }

        if (!exist) {
            if (status == 1)
                temp.put(StoreConst.NAME, "No Tasks done yet");
            else
                temp.put(StoreConst.NAME, "No Tasks to do!");
            list.add(temp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_task_by_name, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And here is the activity which calls it:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LeftTasks extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView tv;
    Button button_vnm;
    Button button_vdt;
    Button button_vpr;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.left_tasks);
        getObjects();

        button_vnm.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_vdt.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_vpr.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void getObjects() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        button_vnm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bViewbyNamelft);
        button_vdt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bViewbydtlft);
        button_vpr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bViewbyprlft);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVleftTasks);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View vvv) {

        Intent i8 = new Intent(this, DisplayTaskList.class);
        i8.putExtra(StoreConst.DoStatus, 0);
        if (R.id.bViewbyNamelft == ((Button) vvv).getId()) {
            i8.putExtra(StoreConst.SortBy, StoreConst.NAME);
        } else if (R.id.bViewbydtlft == ((Button) vvv).getId()) {
            i8.putExtra(StoreConst.SortBy, StoreConst.DATE);
        } else if (R.id.bViewbyprlft == ((Button) vvv).getId()) {
            i8.putExtra(StoreConst.SortBy, StoreConst.PR);

        }

        startActivity(i8);

    }

}
```

Thanks a billion

Comment: Suppose that newTask function is used only in the mentioned activity?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't exaclty get you.

Comment: I mean that you use newTask in the whole app only in the class that you have posted and no where else.

Comment: Oh. It isn't used anywhere else...But why though? That shouldn't cuase replacement of rows right? And anything else that might be an issue?

Comment: You r right. Just in case forgotten function call maybe an issue. While debugging observe the function how many time called and the values passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So I figured it out. I'll type it here for the benefit of those who happen to land on this  page, and may have made a similar mistake (though not very likely):

My error was 2-fold:

First off, I kept having a priority displayed only once in the table (irrespective of how many rows were present which actually had that priority) because I had written db.query as:

```
db.query(StoreConst.TABLENAME, null, StoreConst.STATUS
                + "= " + status, null, StoreConst.PR, null, "'" + StoreConst.PR
                + "' DESC");
```

where the 5th argument is the GROUP BY, and has been set to StoreConst.PR.

Second, I made a very common programming blunder: used == to compare strings in my DisplayTaskList activity. Thus, both the ifs were false, and it went onto the third else, which was to call getTaskByPr() function on manager.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at this line `SQLManager manager = SQLManager.createObject(getApplicationContext());`

You are creating new instance for each new task.

create it only once to open database and  try to call newTask() method statically like this

```
SQLManager.newTask(ed1.getText().toString(), ed2.getText().toString(),
                rId);
```

Comment: But createObject() is a singleton pattern, and only one instance of the object is created, right?  
EDIT: Tried it anyway. Doesn't work, I'm afraid.